# workflows : How to create a Workflow

Tags: workflow

Our team works on solving Tickets that are related to SFDC. Say for example,"The page is not visible".After the solution is provided,generally we don't get any reply from the user or the one who has created the ticket.I want to send an email to the user every night through batch jobs so that he comments on the post with his reply whether the issue is solved or not..We use statuses like "Pending review" and "Pending more information".The condition should be true only the status is one of the either mentioned above.I am new to SFDC and development too.Can anyone help me as how to start this?

Thanks,
Teja K

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using Process Builder or workflow to solve this so no code is required? You could create a timed workflow rule to send an email if no response is received and requeue and use a field update on the workflow to requeue the record. TBH I would go with a process that if the user doesn't reply in 7 days to automatically close it as solved and give warnings to the user that it will be automatically closed if they don't respond.